# Unexplained deletion of PNG files from OSX Desktop 10 seconds after creation

Tags: macos, filesystems, desktop

This bizarre thing has just started happening on my Mac which I don't understand. New .png files copied into ~/Desktop are being deleted within 10 seconds of being placed there.

It doesn't have happen with .txt files. It doesn't happen with .png files that are actually text files. It does happen with .txt or .bin files that are actually .png files (by contents). It doesn't happen with any files that are copied into subfolders of the Desktop.

The Desktop is linked to iCloud, but always has been. I haven't changed any iCloud related settings. I have DropBox installed in a different account on the same machine, but that account in not logged in and DropBox is not running.

Can anyone explain what is going on and why it just started happening?

Here is the test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
do_it() { 
    date; 
    cp $1 Desktop/; 
    count=15; 
    while test $count -gt 0 && sleep 1; do 
        let count=count-1; 
        echo "$(date) $(ls Desktop/$(basename $1))"; 
    done; 
}

run() {
    for n in desktop.png desktop.txt desktop.zero.bin desktop-png.bin desktop-png.txt; do
        do_it Documents/$n
    done;
}

run
```

And here is the output - notice how files that contain .png content are been moved or deleted by something but text files and binary files that don't contain PNGs are not being moved or deleted.

```
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:20 AEST
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:21 AEST Desktop/desktop.png
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:22 AEST Desktop/desktop.png
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:23 AEST Desktop/desktop.png
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:24 AEST Desktop/desktop.png
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:25 AEST Desktop/desktop.png
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:26 AEST Desktop/desktop.png
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:27 AEST Desktop/desktop.png
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:28 AEST Desktop/desktop.png
ls: Desktop/desktop.png: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:29 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop.png: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:30 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop.png: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:31 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop.png: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:32 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop.png: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:33 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop.png: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:34 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop.png: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:36 AEST 
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:37 AEST
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:38 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:39 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:40 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:41 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:42 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:43 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:44 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:45 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:46 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:47 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:48 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:49 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:50 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:51 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:52 AEST Desktop/desktop.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:53 AEST
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:54 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:55 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:56 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:57 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:58 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:09:59 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:00 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:01 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:02 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:03 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:04 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:05 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:06 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:07 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:08 AEST Desktop/desktop.zero.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:09 AEST
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:10 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:11 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:12 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:13 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:14 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:15 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:16 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.bin
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:17 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.bin
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.bin: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:18 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.bin: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:20 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.bin: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:21 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.bin: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:22 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.bin: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:23 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.bin: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:24 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.bin: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:25 AEST 
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:26 AEST
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:27 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:28 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:29 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:30 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:31 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:32 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.txt
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:33 AEST Desktop/desktop-png.txt
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.txt: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:34 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.txt: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:35 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.txt: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:36 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.txt: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:37 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.txt: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:38 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.txt: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:39 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.txt: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:40 AEST 
ls: Desktop/desktop-png.txt: No such file or directory
Thu 14 May 2020 15:10:41 AEST
```

**Update:** thanks to [Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7509065/joseph-sible-reinstate-monica) I installed this [simple audit tool](https://meliot.me/2017/07/02/mac-os-real-time-auditing/) and discovered that it is the "bird" process renaming a file. This "bird" process is associated with iCloud and sure enough when I look into the restored files page on iCloud I can see the files that are disappearing.

So, the next question is: why iCloud doing this and how do I tell it to stop?

Comment: Can you use OpenBSM to audit actions on the file?

Comment: I'll have to learn how to use it, but thanks for the tip!